# changing domain from http to https Zend framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, zend-framework, https

I'am trying to switch from http to https, the app is using the zend framework. The ssl certificate has been installed and everything is in place, in the config.php file I changed the code from

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

To this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://example.com/';
```

But when i just go to the home page everything loads up properly, and when I click on other links(example.com/player or example.com/main) it throws a 404 error for any link other than the home page.

Comment: redirect it by .htaccess file

Comment: Zend or CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://example.com/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';

$config['base_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
```

Comment: @Raza Khan GZap: check this

Comment: I tried the code you gave me but it did not work. the moment i navigate to other views like https://example.com/main, https://exmaple.com/class...etc, it throws an 404 error. But in the routes files when I change the main page to another page, then it would only serve on the main domain site that is example.com.